# Good system for experimenting with shaders in different languages

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx

I'm trying to experiment a bit with shaders and they have been programmed in several different languages (GLSL,  Cg and HLSL). Now most systems (dirrectX, openGL) have only support for one of them. Does anybody know of such a system that easily allows all 3?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know about all three languages, but there is [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) which allows you to write GLSL fragment shaders with different input, all in your web browser.

Comment: The differences between GLSL, HLSL, and Cg are pretty superficial.  If you're looking to experiment with the actual content and function of the shader code as opposed to the syntax, ShaderToy is a good place to start.  You can then pretty easily convert the code to HLSL or Cg as needed.